# How do I get the Active Directory Information with Sharepoint programatically on sharepoint 2013 Farm Solution On Code Behind File?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, active-directory-group

I want to Get the Active Directory names in sharepoint in a list.

To got Know that SharePoint 2013 Has some Hidden URL which Shows Current Active Directory User I wan to get it into List.

```
http://{YourSharepointUrl}/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx
```

Now I want to have list of all the names Displayed on my sharepoint

I am using the code:

```
private static void GetAllSiteUsers()
{
    // Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the server running SharePoint. 
    var sharepointContext = new ClientContext("http://yoursharepointurl/");


}
```

Now I am Getting error it says about assembly reference doesn't exist.So I checked on google and added up this ddl and add the  using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;` reference also.Still Not working.

Please Let me Know what needed to be done Guys

Purpose Of Making Program:To have all the AD Users and Make a work Group so that I can Assign them some right in such a way when assigned grp open something some other URL in iframe shows. and if some one else than other URL in iframe is shown to him.

Thanks IN Advance Guys.

Answer (score 0):

To get all information about active directory user or group you can use

```
PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext (ContextType.Domain, YOUR_DOMAIN);
```

//For User

```
 UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal (pContext);

PrincipalSearcher userSearch = new PrincipalSearcher (userPrincipal);
```

//For Group

```
GroupPrincipal grpPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal (pContext);

PrincipalSearcher grpSearch = new PrincipalSearcher (grpPrincipal);

foreach (UserPrincipal result in userSearch.FindAll())

{
if (result.SamAccountName!= null)

 // Your code
}

foreach (GroupPrincipal result in grpSearch.FindAll())

{

if (result != null)

{

 // Your code 

}
```

Assembly

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

Namespace

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in Server side (Farms solution), so don't use : ClientContext, this is for Client application, not server.

You just have to get the : [User Information List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteuserinfolist.aspx)

You could try somthing like :

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("URLsiteCollection")){
    using(SPWeb web = site.rootWeb){
        SPList userList = web.SiteUserInfoList;
        SPListItemCollection allUsers = userList.Items;
        foreach(SPListItem userItem in allUsers){

            string userEmail = Convert.Tostring(userItem["EMail"]);
            string userName = userItem.Title;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```